# Cant overcome site Browser check with PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to save specified site to server. Tried file_get_contents with no results, finally Got to CURL. After some research and testing the result is:

```
$header=array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
'Host: shakes.pro',
'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
'Connection:keep-alive',
'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
);
set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen ('./a.xml', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init('http://shakes.pro/');
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Works with all other sites I have checked, but this one I need :)
Tested with several different servers, same result
Any ideas?

Comment: maybe because `set_time_limit` is set to 0. Although i must say i am not familiar with libcurl on php :)

Comment: I suggest that the site has cycle redirects. Try to open it into browser. I've no success response. And remove CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER flag if you wish to save it into CURLOPT_FILE.

Comment: playing with set_time_limit  did not gave any results.

Comment: Wizard - The Site shakes.pro is opening in browser. removing CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFE did not gave any results.

Answer (score 0):

Target site will redirects you, if it can't find its own cookies. Here the code that works for me:

```
<?php
$header=array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
);
$fp = fopen ('./a.xml', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init();
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://shakes.pro/1575051');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// this line added for cookies while =307
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, './a.cookiejar');

// if this line enabled, you'll get the result into $result
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks Wizard, you saved my day! Worked like a charm!